# Spring boot security Authentication [This localhost page can’t be found: HTTP ERROR 404] error

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Hope you guys are doing good!

I am implementing spring security for my application. I have given two roles which are "ADMIN" and "employee". If the user has an admin or employee role, they should authenticate and authorize when editing or deleting records. But currently when the user who has an admin role trying to delete the records it should ask for authentication but it's not asking directly it throwing an error msg: This localhost page can’t be found: HTTP ERROR 404

Note: It's not at all asking for authentication & authorization for admin and employee roles. It simply throwing an HTTP 404 error.

Can anyone help me with this what I am doing wrong here?

I have tried this solution but didn't work for me: [Spring boot starter security not authenticating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58345156/spring-boot-starter-security-not-authenticating)

**Here is my controller:**

```
package com.project.ems.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.project.ems.entity.Employee;
import com.project.ems.model.EmployeeModel;
import com.project.ems.repository.EmployeeRepository;

@Controller
public class EmployeeController {
    
    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository repository;
    
    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String  getIndexPage() {
        return  "index";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/addEmployee")
    public String getAddEmployeePage(Model model) {
        EmployeeModel  empModel=new EmployeeModel();
        model.addAttribute("empModel", empModel);
        return "addEmployee";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/saveEmployee")
    public String  saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute("empModel")EmployeeModel  empModel, Model model) {
        Employee e = new Employee();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(empModel, e);
        
        boolean flag=repository.existsById(e.getEmpno());
        if(flag==true) {
            model.addAttribute("message", "Employee with given empno already exist");
        }
        else {
            repository.save(e);
            model.addAttribute("message", "Employee is added to Database");
        }
        return "index";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/listEmployees")
    public String listEmployees(Model model) {
        List<Employee>  empList= repository.findAll();
        
        List<EmployeeModel>  empModelList=new  ArrayList<>();
        
        empList.forEach(e -> {
            
            EmployeeModel emodel=new EmployeeModel();
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(e, emodel);
            empModelList.add(emodel);
            
        });
        
        model.addAttribute("empModelList", empModelList);
        return "employeesList";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/editEmployee")
    public String editEmployeePage(@RequestParam("id") int empno, Model model) {
        Employee  e = repository.findById(empno).get();
        EmployeeModel  emodel=new EmployeeModel();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(e, emodel);
        model.addAttribute("emodel",emodel);
        return "editEmployee";
    
    }
    @PostMapping("/updateEmployee")
    public String updateEmployee(@ModelAttribute("emodel") EmployeeModel emodel) {
        Employee e=new Employee();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(emodel, e);
        repository.saveAndFlush(e);
        return "redirect:listEmployees";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/deleteEmployee")
    public String deleteEmployee(@RequestParam("id") int empno) {
        repository.deleteById(empno);
        return "redirect:listEmployees";
    }
    
}
```

**Here is my security config**

```
    package com.project.ems.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MyApplicationSecurityCofig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http.authorizeRequests().
                        antMatchers("/delete**").
                        hasAnyRole("ADMIN").
                        anyRequest().
                        permitAll(). 
                        and().httpBasic().
                        and().csrf().disable();
            }
            
            @Autowired
            public void configGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
                builder.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("Naresh").password(passwordEncoder.encode("p@ssword")).roles("ADMIN")
                .and().withUser("Suresh").password(passwordEncoder.encode("123456")).roles("Employee");
                
            }
}
```

**Here is my POM.XML :**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>ems</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ems</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Logs**

```
2021-06-02 22:53:42.378[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.project.ems.EmsApplication          [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting EmsApplication using Java 15.0.2 on Naresh with PID 12132 (D:\SpringGuy\ems\target\classes started by Naresh in D:\SpringGuy\ems)
[2m2021-06-02 22:53:42.380[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.project.ems.EmsApplication          [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
[2m2021-06-02 22:53:42.954[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
[2m2021-06-02 22:53:42.997[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 35 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
[2m2021-06-02 22:53:43.427[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port(s): 2121 (http)
[2m2021-06-02 22:53:43.436[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]
[2m2021-06-02 22:53:43.436[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.44]
[2m2021-06-02 22:53:43.689[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
[2m2021-06-02 22:53:43.698[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/ems]   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[2m2021-06-02 22:53:43.698[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mw.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1276 ms
[2m2021-06-02 22:53:43.826[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Starting...
[2m2021-06-02 22:53:44.168[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
[2m2021-06-02 22:53:44.207[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
[2m2021-06-02 22:53:44.257[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.Version                   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.29.Final
[2m2021-06-02 22:53:44.420[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.hibernate.annotations.common.Version  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
[2m2021-06-02 22:53:44.538[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.dialect.Dialect           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
[2m2021-06-02 22:53:45.039[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
[2m2021-06-02 22:53:45.046[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[2m2021-06-02 22:53:45.260[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m12132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mJpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration[0;39m [2m:[0;39m spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
[2m2021-06-02 22:53:45.584[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@204a02a4, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@b889cb6, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@7aaf6bfd, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@5dd2ea0a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@206b959c, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@54c37dab, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@705d72f0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@4777f71e, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@726a5e6a, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@1c06f19c, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@54a5799f]
[2m2021-06-02 22:53:45.679[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
[2m2021-06-02 22:53:45.760[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Adding welcome page template: index
[2m2021-06-02 22:53:45.888[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat started on port(s): 2121 (http) with context path '/ems'
[2m2021-06-02 22:53:45.895[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.project.ems.EmsApplication          [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started EmsApplication in 3.844 seconds (JVM running for 4.596)
[2m2021-06-02 22:53:52.524[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-2121-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/ems]   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2021-06-02 22:53:52.525[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-2121-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2021-06-02 22:53:52.526[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m12132[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-2121-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed initialization in 1 ms
```

Comment: Can you show the log?

Comment: I have added to query please have a look.